# linear transformation of elements of orthogonal bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let an and b n be two different orthonormal bases for $R^n$. Show that there is an orthogonal transformation L from $R^n$ to $R^n$ with L(a i)=bi for each i=1,2,...,n. Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem that says that always exist a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i $ for $i=1,2,...,n$ with $v_i \in V$, $w_i \in W$. This is true in particular for bases.

Now, if $V=\mathbb{R^n}=W$, then the set of all elements of an orthogonal base $A=\{v_1',v_2',\ldots,v_n'\}$ where $v_i'=\dfrac{v_i}{||v_i||}$ and $v_i$ is an element of a basis of V,  has a linear transformation such that $T(v_i)=v_i'$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: find a transfomration of the first basis into a standard normal basis. And then from the standard normal basis to the second basis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try write each element of the basis $(b_i)$ in terms of the basis $(a_j)$.

For example, $b_1=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\langle a_j,b_1\rangle a_j$.

Comment: but the question does not mention any connection between the two bases so how can i do this? thank you

Comment: I've added more information, do you get it?